# RStudio Code Hinting Without Tab

Tags: r, rstudio

Is it possible to have RStudio autocomplete show up every time you start typing?

I have it set up this way in Eclipse and Visual Studio, but RStudio's setting seems to evade me. It's not really about the necessity of having it, but just the security blanket it provides (and maybe save me some key strokes, without having to use Tab every time). It's quite possible this is not even possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the RStudio IDE, not programming.

Comment: This will be a new feature in the next RStudio release. Stay tuned!